# What does the bigrading of forms on a complex manifold correspond to, on the level of complex chains?

Tags: algebraic-topology, differential-forms, complex-geometry

I was thinking about this lately. On a complex manifold of dimension $m$, one has a bigrading on the complexified space of differential forms, namely the forms of type $(p,q)$, say, have $p$ $dz$'s and $q$ $d\bar{z}$'s. Moreover, integration gives us a pairing between complex chains and (complex) differential forms.

My question is now this. What does the bigrading on the complexified space of differential forms correspond to on the level of complex chains?

Edit: by complex chains I mean complex linear combinations of real subvarieties, and not of complex submanifolds. So it is more general. For example, a contour integral would also fall in this category.

Comment: Probably the best way to think about this is in terms of currents, so you should do some reading. But $k$-dimensional complex subvarieties give chains of "type" $(k,k)$. (Along these lines, you might check out the [Hodge conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hodge_conjecture).) But you can certainly integrate differential forms over non-complex cycles (e.g., real submanifolds), and these won't have any meaningful "type."

Comment: @Ted Shifrin, is there absolutely no way to define chains of type $(p,q)$, using perhaps local frames of vector fields of that type?

Comment: I don't think that's what Ted is saying. If $X$ is a complex manifold and $M \subset X$ a real submanifold, then $M$ defines a perfectly good current of integration $[M] = (u \mapsto \int_M u)$ of degree $\dim_{\mathbb R} M$. You can then decompose this real current into a sum of $(p,q)$ currents (however, each piece of the decomposition may no longer correspond to a real submanifold). What's interesting is that if $M$ is a *complex* submanifold, the only $(p,q)$-term that appears is the "middle" one of type $(p,p)$.

Comment: @GunnarÞórMagnússon I understand. I should look up the definition of currents first.